# Adding a background image or gradient to flex box navbar adds a black box behind the elements in the navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a background to my flexbox navbar but this is how it ends up looking every time:

[image: Messed up background]

I want the items within the flexbox including the logo, navigation links, and the search modal to also share the same background.

Here's my code:

```css
* {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #0099F7, #F11712);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="The 8-Bit">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img class="search_modal" src="magnifying-glass.svg" alt="Search" width="30px" height="20px">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to remove `* { background-color: #000000}` as it is a global selector and applies to all elements.

Answer (score 3):

Currently black background is assigned to every element on page (`* { background-color: #000000; }`). If you need page to have black background you can add background to html or/and body tag only (`html, body { background:#000; }`). If you need every element on page to have black background, than you need to declare `background: transparent` on elements which should not have background. Something like

```
.logo, .header nav, .header nav *, .search_modal { background:transparent; }
```

```css
* {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(0.25turn, #0099F7, #F11712);
}
.logo, .header nav, .header nav *, .search_modal { background:transparent; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="The 8-Bit">
    <nav>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Watch">Watch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Mac">Mac</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <img class="search_modal" src="magnifying-glass.svg" alt="Search" width="30px" height="20px">
  </div>
</body>
```